How to log in console only when I debug the application?
I am using Serilog to log events, and I would like to write to console only when I am debbuging the application and when I am run the application in production, I would like to write to files.
But in debug I want to write to file too. Just I would like to avoid to write in console in production because I guess it is not useful because it is a windows service. But in debugging, it is useful to see all the logs in the console.
I would like to configure with a .json file, instead to configure it in code.
This is my .jason file, in which I log in two files, one for information and warnings and another for errors and fatal.
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Filters.Expressions" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByExcluding",
                "Args": { "expression": "@Level = 'Error' or @Level = 'Fatal'" }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "./logs/info.log",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "./logs/error.log",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ]
    }
  }
}

Thanks.
